# why Click event is not calling my function

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why `click` event is not calling `btn()` function.

```js
function btn() {
    var radio = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i > radio.length; i++){
  if (radio[i].checked){
   alert(radio[i].value);
  }
      else{
        alert("lol");
      }
 }
}
```

```html
<input name="r" value="1" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="2" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="3" type="radio">
<button onclick="btn()">hm</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
```

```js
function btn() {
    var radio = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
  if (radio[i].checked){
   alert(radio[i].value);
  }
      else{
        alert("lol");
      }
 }
}
```

```html
<input name="r" value="1" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="2" type="radio">
<input name="r" value="3" type="radio">
<button onclick="btn()">hm</button>
```

Comment: You probably want `<` rather than `<=` or you'll go outside the bounds of the array. In fact if you run your snippet you see this `TypeError: radio[i] is undefined`

Answer (score 4):

> I don't know why click event is not calling btn() function.

It is, it's just that it never gets into your loop as it has a logical error

```
for (var i = 0; i > radio.length; i++){
```

`i` is *never* greater than `radio.length`. that was supposed to be a less than sign

```
for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
```

Comment: thanks it's just typing miske but when i was debuging my code i thought function is not event called.

Comment: @akash - no problam glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Your handler does run, its your for loop that is wrong. It never iterates as you have `i > radio.length` it should be `i < radio.length`.

I would also add that binding events using html `onclick` and such is not a good idea. It is best advised to use `addEventListener`.

`document.getElementById('goBtn').addEventListener('click', btn);`

This gives you much greater control of the events that you have bound, allows you to easily remove them and add multiple for the same event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j375r0gs/

Comment: Good mention about `eventListeners`!